# URL Rewrite keep %20 in Query String

Tags: .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting, query-string

I am trying to make a rewrite rule to move all pdf's on my site to point to a specific page and then use a Query String as the pdf's current file path to do a look up in a dictionary to see if that url is in my dictionary if it is redirect them to the correct page.  The catch is my dictionary of urls has %20 and when I pull the query string it turns the `%20` in a space.  Thanks for any and all help.

Can you rewrite it to keep the %20 in the query string?

Example URL: `/example/example/Big%20Small%20Something%20Pad.pdf`

My Rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*)\.pdf$  /redirectPDF.aspx?pdf=$1.pdf [NE,QSA]
```

Current Query String Output: `Big Small Something Pad.pdf`

What I want it to look like is `Big%20Small%20Someting%20Pad.pdf`

Comment: Are you using ISAPI or Apache?

Comment: Just thinking around the problem of your "dictionary" having literal `%20` in the filenames... can you not simply URL encode the parameter value before looking it up in the dictionary? What server-side language are you using?

Comment: I am using asp.net / c# ... yes this could prolly be done but I was just thought a rewrite could handle this.

Comment: I don't know if asp.net/C# is anything like PHP in this respect, but PHP itself URL decodes the parameter values (`%20` to _space_), however, there are other variables in PHP that hold the original (%-encoded) request.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `NE` flag. According to ISAPI docs:
 http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/RewriteRule.htm:

> **noescape|NE**
>
> Don't escape output. By default ISAPI_Rewrite will encode all non-ANSI >characters as %xx hex codes in output.

So it looks like you simply want to omit the `NE` so that it'll encode the output like it does by default.

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*)\.pdf$  /redirectPDF.aspx?pdf=$1.pdf [QSA]
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried and it does not work.